# How to enable text cursor in IBMPC BIOS graphics mode 16 (INT 10H/AX=0010H)?

Tags: assembly, dos, bios, vga

Going into graphics video mode 16 (INT 10H/AX=0010) there's no text cursor.

Tried this with both a physical old IBMPC with onboard VGA/AMIBIOS(1.16) running DOS, and in DOSBOX.

I've tried messing with these to no effect, as they seem to be "text mode" only (not graphics):

- "cursor shape" (`INT 10H/AH=01/CX=0D0EH`)
- "cursor emulation" (`INT 10H/AH=12H/AL=0/BL=34H`)

Seems like the cursor should be easy to turn on and off, is there a different BIOS function for this to turn it on?

Answer (score 3):

Mode 10h is a 16-color graphics mode (640x350). In the graphics modes the cursor is not displayed although BIOS does keep track of its position, but that's about it.

The position that BIOS maintains for this invisible cursor will correspond to a character cell layout (8x14) even though the screen is *all pixels addressable*.

If you want a cursor you'll have to draw it yourself graphically (a short line) or you can alternatively display a text character and a space to create the effect of a blinking character.

Comment: Sounds like I'll have to create a TSR to manage this so it works in DOS etc. My DOS app draws graphs but also can prompt the user for new data values, and to shell commands out to DOS while the graph is onscreen. Guess I'd have to intercept video printing to keep the cursor in the right place, undrawing it when it moves and redrawing it at the new location in inverse. Ugh, maybe there's a driver out there somewhere.. I'll sniff around.

Comment: If your TSR simply inverses all of the pixels in the 8x14 rectangle where the cursorposition points to and keeps doing so on a timed basis, you're set. Of course, once the position changes you need to restore the previous rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, I could see doing a blinking cursor off the timer interrupt, say XOR'ing the bottom scanline, but it might leave garbage behind e.g if the screen is scrolled/cleared. Might have to intercept INT 10 and be sure to turn the cursor off before doing the real call, then turning it back on again after.

Answer (score 1):

EGA/VGA videomode Nr. 10h is **graphic** (640*350), see [Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm#Table10), and the BIOS services that you tried messing with are for **text** modes only.
You will have to draw the cursor by yourself, I'm afraid.

On the other hand, you can paint the cursor in arbitraty shape and position it on the screen with pixel-granularity in graphic modes.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I'm going to look through the BIOS source in the IBM tech ref manual just to double check if there's any provision for this, as it'll be hard to do this otherwise.. sounds like it'd have to be a TSR device driver.

Answer (score 0):

Under Dosbox, you can use dos interrupt call (int 0x33) to manipulate mouse.
I wrote a simple example, you can assemble this with fasm:

```
org 0x100

;; Init Data Segment
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax

;; Init screen
mov ah, 0x00    ; Set video mode
mov al, 0x10    ; 640x350 graphics
int 0x10

mov ah, 0x0b    ; Set color palette
mov bh, 0x00    ; Set current
mov bl, 0x03    ; Color: Cyan
int 0x10

mov ax, 0x0000  ; Reset mouse cursor
int 0x33

mov ax, 01          ; Show mouse cursor
int 0x33

hang:
    hlt
    jmp hang


;; Magic number
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: Thanks, though actually it's the /text cursor/ I'm trying to turn on in graphics mode, not the mouse.